# Float division by zero in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The values:

```
n=60
r=10.0/100/12=0.008333333333333333  #I know these numbers are weird
p=21.247044711268334
```

This is the line that gives the error:

```
RemainingLoanBalance=principal*((1+r)**n-(1+r)**p)/((1+r)**n-1)
```

Error:

> Float division by zero

I don't understand this.

My sys.float_info:

> sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)

Comment: What is the error? What are the values for `principal`, `r`, `n`, and `p`? Edit your question and provide these, we need to be know and be able to reproduce this in order to help.

Comment: As the title (error msg) says, you're trying to divide by zero. Find the dividend that ends up being zero and make sure it doesn't end up zero. You only have one division here so it's somewhere in `((1+r)**n-1)` (I assume `n==1` in your example)

Comment: If r is `-1`, you will be dividing by zero.  Dividing by zero is pretty difficult, even for a computer.  Add a `print(str(r))` statement just before that line of code that it's crashing on.  That will tell you what `r` is before it calculates that expression.

Comment: At least on the 64-bit machine I am using, those numbers won't cause a division-by-zero error. You need `r` to be 13 orders of magnitude smaller before the denominator becomes 0.

Comment: What is the value of `sys.float_info` on your machine? It's possible the machine you are on has less precision than mine.

Comment: got this when i tried that : sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1) # i mean the sys.float_info